# How to prove that $x^2 - 3y^2 = 11$ is not possible as long as x and y are integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

Really No idea how I can go about solving it. What I did was,

$$y = \sqrt{\frac{x^2 - 11}{3}}$$

but cant go beyond that. Can anybody help?

Comment: are you familiar with modulo operation?

Comment: For $y$ to be integer, you need $\frac{x^2-11}{3}$ to be the square of an integer, and in particular an integer. For that you need $x^2 - 11$ to be divisible by $3$...

Comment: I am, and I'm also aware that 11 ≡ 2 (mod 3) should prove this answer, but dont know how to get to this

Comment: Do you know Pell-Fermat Equation?

Comment: So, how can I prove that $x^2 - 11$ will not be divisible by 3?

Comment: Is that the one which says $$x^2 + ny^2 = 1$$ has infinite solutions?

Comment: Somewhat...but, what does it say for integers?

Comment: I dont know ... :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x^2 \equiv 0, 1 \pmod 3$$

in fact $0^2 \equiv 0, 1^2 \equiv 1, 2^2 = 4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

of course $3y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ (it is divisible by $3$)

so

$$x^2 - 3y^2 \equiv 0, 1 \pmod 3$$ but $$11 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$$ so it is impossible.

Comment: nice solution...+1

Comment: Gee, I feel stupid. Thanks a lot :) nice solution.

Comment: you're very welcome! :-)

Comment: A little concise : $$x^2-3y^2=11\implies x^2\equiv11\pmod3\equiv2$$ But $x\equiv0,\pm1\pmod3\implies x^2\equiv0,1$